# Interesting variation to the subset sum problem

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, dynamic-programming, np-hard

An interesting variation of the subset sum problem was presented to me by a friend from work:

Given a set S of positive integers, of size n, and integers a and K, is there a subset R (of the set S) that contains **exactly a elements**, whose sum is equal to K?

He claims that this can be done with time complexity O(nka), I was unable to come up with a dynamic programming algorithm that achieved this running time. Can it be done?

Comment: This is not off-topic, but you may get better answers on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Is there any restriction on the range of numbers?

Comment: @Gunner, I think we can assume positive numbers (will edit)
@Space_C0wb0y, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done if k and a are small enough, so that we can declare an array

```
bool found[a][k]
```

You would iterate over each value in S and iterate over every state in the **found** array to obtain a new state.

Say, for the indexes of a=1 and k = 7, and the current value from S being 7,

if found[1][7] is true, then you can also be sure that found[2][14] is also true.

When the iteration ends, all you need to do is check that [a][k] is true or not.

Comment: Not sure that this approach meets the time complexity bound, since it looks like you have to iterate over subsets of S, not individual elements.

Comment: Not really, I am iterating over elements of S and not subset.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz What's the rationale for "if found[1][7] is true, then you can also be sure that found[2][14] is also true"? If you have {1, 2, 7} as the input set S, then found[1][7] is true but found[2][14] is false right? Subset can't take one element twice

Comment: @CharlesW. You consider each element from S only once. If you were to code this up, the outermost loop would iterate over each value in S.

Answer (score 3):

Let S = {s1,\ldots,sn}

Let P(j,K,a) be true iff it is possible to find a elements in s1,\ldots,sj that sum up to K.

Then P(j,K,a) = P(j-1, K-sj, a-1) OR P(j, K, a) (either sj is needed or it is not needed).

The algorithm then consists of filling out 3-D table of dimension n by K+1 by a+1. Each entry takes constant time to fill, hence the time (and space) complexity is  O(nKa)

Comment: When I read the above marked answer, this is how I interpreted/implemented it. Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't it be P(j,K,a) = P(j-1, K-S[j], a-1) OR P(j-1, K, a) ?